# Returning lowest value (and associating key) for each key/value pair in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary similar to the following (but with more keys and a varying number of nested values).

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {11: [139.04185], 3: [2.661], 5: [12.6, 63.046]})
```

I'm trying return the lowest value for each key.  I.e. the desired result would be:

```
11   139.04185

3    2.661

5    12.6
```

I've tried looping through the dictionary with a duplicate dictionary which resulted in a very long and unfortunate looking for loop; which especially because of the duplicate dictionary is surely not the solution.

*There are other questions here regarding the single max/min value in a dictionary, and finding the max/min using a 'list' of keys, but nothing I've been able to adapt to this problem.*

How could this be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop over the dict, print each key `k` and the min of the `d[k]`values

```
for k in d:
    print("{:<6}{}".format(k, min(d[k])))
11    139.04185
3     2.661
5     12.6
```

Use `str.format's`  [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) if you want the output aligned

Comment: Perfect! It works like a charm! It'll be quick as well which is what I was looking for...unlike my horrendous idea dealing with indexes etc.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

it would be faster to get both key and value from the dict, d[k] may be slower

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print("{:<6}{}".format(k, min(v)))
```